# LXC cpu.shares doesn't work

Tags: lxc, cgroups

From yesterday I'm struggling with problem with LXC containers and limiting CPU resources per container. In my case command like `lxc-cgroup -n srv50 cpu.shares 100` doesn't bring any results - containers still use CPU equally.

I'm using Centos 7 & LXC 1.0.8. All machines where I was checking that had the same effect: setting `cpu.shares` doesn't do anything.

Here's systemd-cgtop screen, from my 2 cores VM:

```
Path                                                                             Tasks   %CPU   Memory  Input/s Output/s

/                                                                                  178  199.7   360.8M        -        -
/lxc                                                                                 -  198.0    16.8M        -        -
/lxc/srv51                                                                           7   99.8     8.4M        -        -
/lxc/srv50                                                                           7   98.2     8.4M        -        -
/system.slice/NetworkManager.service                                                 2      -        -        -        -
/system.slice/auditd.service                                                         1      -        -        -        -
```

Container `srv50` has `cpu.shares` set to 100, whereas `srv51` set to 50. Both containers run command `dd if=/dev/urandom | bzip2 -9 >> /dev/null`. I was expecting one container takes 66% and other 133% CPU (or something like that), but both use 100%.

One hint. When I was trying find which one container uses the most CPU I noticed in `htop` tool that all containers have the same cgroup: `:name=systemd:/user.slice/user-0.slice/session-1.scope?` - not sure whether this is correct or not - just noticed that.

Limiting memory works, CPU nope.

I've just done testing cgroups and I can't set `cpu.share` for any process (by moving it to some group), so it's consistent. Smells like some missing kernel switch.

2: There's a bug in my example. To see difference in load on 2 cores machine, we must have at least 2 processes running 100% per container. Anyway, this is not an issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the issue in this case was with testing this feature. It works as expected. The only one issue I had on other cloud VM with 2 cores. As I don't need it, I won't be thinking about it any more. :) Cheers!